# Crear un array por teclado, rellenarlo y saber el mayor

Tags: java, eclipse

Crea un array de números de un tamaño pasado por teclado, el array contendrá números aleatorios entre 20 y 30, indica cuál es el mayor de todos

Me queda saber como hacer que sean numeros aleatorios que entre 20 y 30 y saber cual es el mayor de todos, se poner que el ultimo sea 30 pero no que el primero.

```
    //variables
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 =0;
    
    //creamos las variables
    System.out.println("Inserte el numero de posiciones del array: ");
    num2 = teclado.nextInt();

    int num[]= new int [num2];

    System.out.println("Creado array de: " + num.length);

    System.out.println("El array es el siguiente: ");
    for (int i=0 ; i<num2 ; i++) {
        

        num[i]= (int)(Math.random()*(30-1+1)+1);
        System.out.println("En la posición: " + i + " se a asignado el numero: " + num[i]);
    }
    //hacemos formula para que segun elijamos x numero saque todos los que elijamos
    System.out.println("Indica el ultimo digito:" );
    num3 = teclado.nextInt();
    
    for (int x=0 ; x<num.length ; x++) {
        if(num3==num[x]%10) {
            System.out.println("Los numeros que terminan por ese digito son: " + num[x]);
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hola Nerea, bienvenida a StackOverflow. Lo que has publicado parece el enunciado de un ejercicio del instituto. Para que te podamos ayudar deberías poner todo lo que has intentado hasta ahora. Poner el código de cómo creas el array, como generas los números aleatorios primos y lo que has hecho para buscar el mayor (si utilizas añgún método de ordenamiento o algo así). Si has avanzado algo y te has quedado a mitad y no sabes seguir, publica hasta donde hayas llegado y explica que errores te da o dónde te has atascado.

Comment: Deberías editar tu pregunta (botón justo debajo de tu pregunta) y poner el código, sino corres el riesgo de que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo e arreglado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitarias usar una instancia Random() y mediante un for llenarias el tamaño del arreglo con los numeros aleatorios de 20-30 y con un segundo for el mayor de ese arreglo

```
import java.util.*;

public class random{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random numAleatorio = new Random();
    Scanner teclado =new Scanner(System.in);

 
System.out.println("Inserte el numero de posiciones del array: ");
 int posicion = teclado.nextInt();
 int num[]= new int [posicion];
 int mayor=0;


 for (int i=0;i<num.length;i++ ) {
    num[i]=numAleatorio.nextInt(30-20+1) + 20;//numeros entre 20-30
  //num[i]= (int) (Math.random() * (30-20+1)+20);//otra forma  
 }
 
 for (int j=0;j<num.length;j++ ) {
        if(num[j]>mayor){
          mayor=num[j];
        }
    }   
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
    System.out.println("El mayor de todo es :"+ mayor);
}
}
```